# android post issue, why I receive "No route to host"

Tags: android, post, routes

Anybody can help me? When calling `HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);`

It throws an `IOException`, which shows **"No route to host"**.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();   
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlstr.toString());             

List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login_User_Name", namestr));  
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login_User_Password", passwordstr));          
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, HTTP.UTF_8);  
request.setEntity(formEntity);  
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

my web soucecode is below

```
<div class="S-Login" id="S-Login">
    <div class="h" JNetDriftBar="title">
        <span>
                    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="lt" Lge="Login_User_Name"></div>
    <div class="ln">
        <div class="N-Ipt">
            <div class="Nir"></div>
            <div class="Nil"></div>
            <div class="Nic">
                <input type="text" id="Login_User_Name" JNetDriftBar=":focus" value="" maxlength="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lt" Lge="Login_User_Password"></div>
    <div class="ln">
        <div class="N-Ipt">
            <div class="Nir"></div>
            <div class="Nil"></div>
            <div class="Nic">
                <input type="password" id="Login_User_Password" value="" maxlength="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lt" Lge="Login_Language"></div>
    <div class="ln" style="text-align:left;">
        <div class="N-Select">
            <div class="N-Ipt">
                <div class="Nir"></div>
                <div class="Nil"></div>
                <div class="Nic">
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="Login_Language" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="NOpt Nc Lg" id="Login-allLanCot">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lt"></div>
    <div class="ln">
        <a href="javascript:;" hidefocus="true" class="N-Btn-1" onmousedown="$$.md(this,'N-Btn-1dw',event);" onmouseup="$$.mu(this,'N-Btn-1dw',event);" Lge="Login_Enter" onclick="Entry.submit();"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or how can I connect use the url? http://192.168.8.100/protocol.csp?fname=security&opt=pwdchk&name=???&pwd1=???&function=set

Comment: Is the Android system running on the same network?  192.168.#.# is reserved for private addresses.  More info @  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the domain name in the URL is invalid (does not exist), you have no network connection, or your DNS server is incorrectly set. Verify that you can browse to the URL in the Android browser.

EDIT: also, make sure you have the INTERNET permission. Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Thank Femi!I use the IP to connect,my android can browse web.