# How to connect TIdTCPClient to TIdTCPServer on Android/IOS?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, c++builder, indy

Indy `TIdTCPClient` Error: `socket error # 113 no rout to host` when connecting from Android to PC.

Hello, i know i asked a lot of questions about Indy Components lately, but i'm having a real problem trying to connect `TIdTCPClient` in my Android device to `TIdTCPServer` which is on my PC Windows 10.

I have to add that i am using **WIFI** on **LAN** network, also all devices have **WIFI** access.

Also, i have to mention that my windows 10 **FireWall** is **Off**, so it cannot be **firewalled** somehow.
In addition, there's no antiviruses active in my windows 10 platform, not even **MCAfee**.

***This is the error i get when i try to connect from my Android to PC***:

```
socket error # 113 no route to host
```

**Note:** I can connect when i use both sides `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer` on same **Machine**.

**Connection Template:**

This is my problem:

1- Connect from **PC1** to **PC2** = "***Failed***".

2- Connect from **PC1** to **PC1** = "***Success***".

3- Connect from **PC1** to **Android/IOS** = "***Failed***".

4- Connect from **Android/IOS** to **PC1** = "***Failed***".

On **Failed** i get the error above.

**XML UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.embarcadero.watcher"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0"
        android:installLocation="auto">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="watcher" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">



        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="watcher"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="watcher" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android post issue, why I receive “No route to host”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645555/android-post-issue-why-i-receive-no-route-to-host)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket Error #113 No route to host. DELPHI FIREMONKEY XE6-ANDROID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850314/socket-error-113-no-route-to-host-delphi-firemonkey-xe6-android)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but is changing the `AndroidManifest.xml` will be from the application directory , or using the IDE better?, also after changing does it require compiling the project?

Comment: Use the IDE. It's in the Uses Permissions section of the Project Options for the Android Target

Comment: Still getting the same error even when i changed the `AndroidManifest.xml` from project options, **See Update**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem in my **WIFI Router**, because when i changed to another router it worked fine, anyway thanks for your help